# Predict next binary value in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, sequence, predict

I'm trying to create a check which would pick up unusual changes in the binary data received on a monthly basis.  My DataFrame (see example below) has multiple entities which a on monthly basis get assigned an 'exclusion flag' (1=exclusion, 0=inclusion).

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Date': [20210101, 20210201,20210301,20210401,20210501,
              20210101, 20210201,20210301,20210401,20210501,
              20210101,20210201,20210301,20210401,20210501,
             20210101,20210201,20210301,20210401,20210501,
             20210101,20210201,20210301,20210401,20210501,
             20210101,20210201,20210301,20210401,20210501,], 
              
     'Entity': ['A','A','A','A','A',
                'B','B','B','B','B',
                'C','C','C','C','C',
                 'D','D','D','D','D',
               'E','E','E','E','E',
               'F','F','F','F','F'],
    'Exclusion': [1,1,1,1,1,
                  0,0,0,1,1,
                  0,0,0,1,0,
                  1,0,1,0,1,
                  1,1,1,1,0,
                 0,1,1,1,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.columns

##pd.melt(df, id_vars =['Date'],value_vars='Entity')


pd.pivot(df, index=['Date'], columns = 'Entity',values = 'Exclusion')
```

If I was to validate the **May 2022 data** based on the trends observed during the previous months the check would :

1. Accept the the new value for Entity A (value 1 is consistent with the history)
2. Accept the new value for Entity B (some changes observed in history but no month to month change)
3. Accept the change for Entity C (value changes from 1 to 0 but zero is in line with the historic values, e.g. the condition for acceptance could be : we had more 0's in the past than 1's so i am okay with this value reverting to 0)
4. Accept the change for Entity D (values are regularly flip flopping between 0 and 1 )
5. Flag the change for Entity E as suspicious (first occurrence of 0)
6. Flag the change for Entity F as suspicious  (not a first occurrence of 0 but however then trend of the past few months have been broken).

Could anyone recommend an easy method to approach this problem without applying heavy machine learning?
I am not aiming for a perfect check that would 100% satisfy the 6 conditions but just something that would attempt a simple prediction what is more likely to occur as a next month's value (1 or 0) based on the past  data.

One thing I have tried was np.polyfit (using month as my x although my data is not impacted by seasonality)  however only managed to apply to a scenario dealing with 1 entity, in my case the likely number of entities will be approx 3K, the number of months of data is something i could play around with and apply some limits (e.g. consider only last 6 months). I'm a python newbie and a first time poster here so hope I explained my problem clear enough - please let me know if you need any additional information.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use rolling average.

```
#First regrup by Entity:
entity_group = df.groupby('Entity')
# cycle in groups
out = np.array([])
for name, group in entity_group:
    print(f'Entity: {name}')
    out = np.append(out, group["Exclusion"].rolling(3).mean().diff())
df['var']=out
```

output:

[image]